# Firefox: Open popup window repeatedly with the same properties (position, width/height)

Tags: javascript, popup, window

> Note: This works perfectly in Google Chrome, it is a problem in Firefox (42.0)

Ultimately, given a page that opens a popup, I want to remember the properties of the popup on close and reopen it in the same position and with the same dimensions.

A bit more formally, I want to do the following:

1. User clicks on 'open popup' button
2. Open popup window
3. User resizes and moves popup window
4. User closes popup window
5. User clicks on 'open popup' button
6. Open popup window in the same position and with the same dimensions that the window had when user last closed it.

I tried to store the position / dimensions on `unload` event in a cookie and pass these values next time to window.open() but there is always some pixels shift.

Essentially the problem I see is that the properties of the window do not match the ones passed to `window.open()`.

Small demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/8b2j3352/24 (you need to allow popups)

I get `innerWidth 546 innerHeight 218 outerWidth 561 outerHeight 294 screenX 109 screenY 54`

None of these values match the properties provided to `window.open()`: `"width=500, height=200, top=50, left=100"`

Do you know any way to reopen the popup in the same position and with the same dimensions?

Note that this works as expected in Google Chrome, it reports `innerWidth 500 innerHeight 200 outerWidth 510 outerHeight 260 screenX 100 screenY 50`

Comment: Is it always off by the same amount?  Perhaps you can just adjust your numbers by a small calculation each time?  I did a few tests in IE & Chrome with various settings; it's all over the place.

Comment: @spozun The differences do not seem sensible-enough to me that I would feel comfortable doing some simple adjustment.

Comment: I have submitted a bug to Mozilla for this: [link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1231070)

Answer (score 0):

The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant. The question is about a popup browser window, not any element inside.